# Linear Fit does not adjust b independently form a

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using the following gnuplot script to plot a linear fit:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set term cairolatex
set output "linear_fit.tex"
c = 299792458.
x(x) = c / x
y(x) = x
h(x) = a * x + b
fit h(x) "linear_fit.dat" u (x($1)):(y($2)) via a,b
plot "linear_fit.dat" u (x($1)):(y($2)) w points title "", \
    (h(x)) with lines linecolor rgb "black" title "Linear Fit"
```

However, after the iterations converge, b is always 1.0: https://dpaste.de/ozReq/

How can I get gnuplot to adjust b as well as a?

**Update:** Repeating the fit command a few hundred times with alternating `via a`/`via b` does give pretty good results, but that just can't be how it's supposed to be done.

**Update 2:** Here's the data in `linear_fit.dat`:

```
# lambda, V
360e-9 1.119
360e-9 1.148
360e-9 1.145
400e-9 0.949
400e-9 0.993
400e-9 0.971
440e-9 0.883
440e-9 0.875
440e-9 0.863
490e-9 0.737
490e-9 0.728
490e-9 0.755
540e-9 0.575
540e-9 0.571
540e-9 0.592
590e-9 0.457
590e-9 0.455
590e-9 0.482
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `linear_fit.dat` and a set of typical command line inputs `$1` and `$2`, please? I just tried this with a "home-made" `linear_fit.dat` and could not reproduce your observation.

Comment: @Schorsch I updated the question with a link to `linear_fit.dat`. `$1` and `$2` don't refer to command line inputs, it merely indicates that `gnuplot` should use the first and second columns of the input data set.

Answer (score 3):

I think your troubles stem from the fact that your `x`-values are very large (on the order of `10e14`).

If you do not provide gnuplot with an initial guess for `a` and `b`, it will assume `a=1` and `b=1` as starting points for the fit. However, this is a poor initial guess:

[image]

Please note the log scale on both the `x`- and `y`-axis.
From the [gnuplot documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-8900027.4):

> fit may, and often will get "lost" if started far from a solution, where SSR is large and changing slowly as the parameters are varied, or it may reach a numerically unstable region (e.g., too large a number causing a floating point overflow) which results in an "undefined value" message or gnuplot halting.
>
> To improve the chances of finding the global optimum, you should set the starting values at least roughly in the vicinity of the solution, e.g., within an order of magnitude, if possible. The closer your starting values are to the solution, the less chance of stopping at another minimum. One way to find starting values is to plot data and the fitting function on the same graph and change parameter values and replot until reasonable similarity is reached. The same plot is also useful to check whether the fit stopped at a minimum with a poor fit.

In your case, such starting values could be:

```
a = 1e-15
b = -0.5
```

I obtained these values by eye-balling [your range of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIpeV.png).
With those starting values, the linear fit results in:

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================

a               = 1.97355e-015     +/- 6.237e-017   (3.161%)
b               = -0.5             +/- 0.04153      (8.306%)
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

You can play with the control setting of `fit` (such as setting `FIT_LIMIT = 1.e-35`) or the starting values to achieve a better fit than this.

---

**EDIT**

While I still have not been able to coax gnuplot into modifying both parameters `a`, `b` at the same time, I found an alternate approach using R. I am aware that there are many other (scripting) languages that can perform a linear fit and this question was about gnuplot. However, the required effort with R appeared to be minimal.
Here's an example, which, when saved as `linear_fit.R` and called with

```
R CMD BATCH linear_fit.R
```

will provide the two coefficients of the linear fit, that gnuplot failed to provide.

```
y <- c(1.119, 1.148, 1.145, 0.949, 0.993, 0.971, 0.883, 0.875, 0.863, 
       0.737, 0.728, 0.755, 0.575, 0.571, 0.592, 0.457, 0.455, 0.482)
x <- c(3.60E-007, 3.60E-007, 3.60E-007, 4.00E-007, 4.00E-007, 
       4.00E-007, 4.40E-007, 4.40E-007, 4.40E-007, 4.90E-007, 
       4.90E-007, 4.90E-007, 5.40E-007, 5.40E-007, 5.40E-007, 
       5.90E-007, 5.90E-007, 5.90E-007)
c = 299792458.
x <- c/x
lm.out <- lm(y ~ x)
svg("linear_fit.svg")
plot(x,y) 
abline(lm.out,col="red")
summary(lm.out)
```

You will end up with an `svg`-file that contains the plot and a `linear_fit.Rout` text file. In there you'll find the following coefficients:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -5.429e-01  4.012e-02  -13.53 3.55e-10 ***
x            2.037e-15  6.026e-17   33.80 2.61e-16 ***
```

So, in the terminology of the original question, we obtain:

```
a =  2.037e-15
b = -5.429e-01
```

These values are very close to the values you quoted from alternating the fit.

---

In case the comments get purged, these questions were identified as related:

[What is gnuplot's internal representation of floating point numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052115/what-is-gnuplots-internal-representation-of-floating-point-numbers)

[Gnuplot behaves oddly in polynomial fit. Why is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073925/gnuplot-behaves-oddly-in-polynomial-fit-why-is-that)

Comment: That's unfortunately not what it's supposed to be. It should look like this: http://i.imgur.com/IGwRHZ1.png. <- That's what I get after alternating the fit between `via a` and `via b` 1000 times.

Comment: @KlemensBaum please see my revised answer

Comment: Thanks for tanking the time to look into this once again. Setting a good initial value for `b` yields much better results, but `gnuplot` once again did not try to change `b` at all (it's still `-0.5` after your fit). I'm puzzled as to why it keeps ignoring the second variable. Could this be a bug in `gnuplot` or are we both overlooking something crucial? You would think linear fits are a feature that is extensively tested. FYI the values I get via the "alternating fit" approach are `a = 2.03705e-15` and `b = -0.542891`.

Comment: @KlemensBaum I think the issue is really that the two values are so significantly different in magnitude. If you read more in the documentation it is mentioned that gnuplot will have issues there. And I think `1e-15` is very close to a floating point representation of `0`. Maybe scaling, as I had initially proposed, will yield better results quicker (for my trials with more coherent orders of magnitude it would change `a` and `b`)

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052115/what-is-gnuplots-internal-representation-of-floating-point-numbers), `gnuplot` internally uses doubles, which means that even some numbers smaller than `1e-307` are representable. Even if it were to use single precision floats, `1e-37` is representable. Since these orders of magnitude occur very commonly in scientific data, `gnuplot` really ought support them.

Comment: @KlemensBaum yes and no. I think it is not just the actual range of values but the ratio of `y` to `x` - your slope is very small. So when Gnuplot tries to adjust the slope, the changes are very small. Depending on the settings, it is "converged" very quickly - without actually having changed much. So - scientific or not - I still think that one value on the order of `1e14` and the other on the order of `1` may be unfortunate and require scaling.

Comment: @KlemensBaum Have a look at [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073925/gnuplot-behaves-oddly-in-polynomial-fit-why-is-that). It seems someone had a problem very similar to yours. And there as here, I think in the end it boils down to the algorithm used for the fit. And yes, we probably both tried playing with `FIT_LIMIT` and the like. However, the slope adjusts quickly and "converges" (even for `FIT_LIMIT  = 1e-35` - and `b` never changes.